# How to finish highlight from selected button when new button is selected?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, highlighting, activity-finish

```
-(IBAction)choiceOne:(id)sender{

    if ([Choice2 isSelected]) {
        [Choice2 performSelector:@selector(finishHighlight:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];
        score = score -4;
        score = score+8;
        NSLog(@"Score updated %i touched from choice 1 ",score);
        [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];

        checker =1 ;

    }else if ([Choice3 isSelected]) {
          [Choice3 performSelector:@selector(finishHighlight:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];
        score = score -2;
        score = score+8;
        NSLog(@"Score updated %i touched from choice 1 ",score);
        [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];

        checker =1 ;
    }
    else {
        score = score+8;
        NSLog(@"Score updated %i touched from choice 1 ",score);
        [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];

        checker =1 ;
    }


}
```

I have to finish highlight's from selected button if any other button is pressed from menu

```
- (void)doHighlight:(UIButton*)b {
    [b setHighlighted:YES];
}    
-(void)finishHighlight:(UIButton*)a{

    [a setHighlighted:NO];

}
```

these are the functions which I'm using in above  ... and

Comment: I think you're calling the same action at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be super easy if both the buttons are connected to "IBOutlets". Are they?
Like for example:

```
IBOutlet UIButton * mode1;
IBOutlet UIButton * mode2;
```

parameters a & b are ignored in this particular...

```
-(IBAction) button1Pressed:(id)sender {

    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton1:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)highlightButton1:(UIButton *)a { 
        [mode1 setHighlighted:YES];
    [mode2 setHighlited:NO];
}
-(IBAction) button2Pressed:(id)sender {

    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton2:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)highlightButton2:(UIButton *)b { 
    [mode1 setHighlighted:NO];
    [mode2 setHighlited:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes.. simply use iterations to get the button and set them as normal OR you can have an instance var which stores the previous selected button. so you simply have to change the state for this button. So its up to you which method suites you better.